# nested loop error when displaying in html after retrieve from API

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to ionic 3 and angular. Basically I wanted to create a list with header (data from MySQL database through PHP API). The header will display the `category` while the `items` will go to `ion-item` section.

However when I try to call the 2nd `ngFor` it throws me error as  shown below in the picture. I notice a lot people use GET method while I am using POST method which are harder to find solution out there. Please enlighten, thanks in advance.

**JSON**

[image]

**home.ts**

```
this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {
  let headers: any = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
    options: any = { "username": val },
    url: any = "path_to_my_api";

  this.http.post(url, options, headers)
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.prods = data.products;
    },
      (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
});
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let prod of prods | async">
    <ion-list-header>
      {{prod.category}}
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let myitem of prod.item | async">
        <ion-avatar item-start>

        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>haha{{myitem.code}}</h2>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: According to the error message, item is an object, not an array.

Comment: how to make it become an array? But in console it is array, am I right? So weird

Comment: No, your second ngfor is entirely unnecessary. You’ve already begun to iterate over the array.

Comment: I want all the items to be grouped in the category, if I only use 1 ngfor, the category will display as duplicate for every single item.

Comment: Ok, I see. I will update my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Logic:

```
this.http.post(url, options, headers)
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    const categoryMap = data.products.reduce((categories, prod) => {
      if (categories[prod.category]) {
        categories[prod.category].push(prod);
      } else {
        categories[prod.category] = [prod];
      }

      return categories;
    }, {});

    this.categories = Object.keys(categoryMap).map(category => ({
      category,
      products: categoryMap[category]
    });
  }, (error: any) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Template:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let cat of categories | async">
  <ion-list-header>
    {{cat.category}}
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let prod of cat.products | async"> <!-- not sure if async pipe is necessary here though -->
    <ion-avatar item-start></ion-avatar>
    <h2>haha{{prod.item.code}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

To clarify, the final structure of your data will look like this:

```
this.categories = [
  {
    category: "Beer Bottles",
    products: [
      {
        item: {code: 'whatever'},
        category: "Beer Bottles"
      },
      {
        item: {code: 'something else'},
        category: "Beer Bottles"
      },
      ...etc.
    ]
  },
  {
    category: "Beer Draught",
    products: [ ...relevant products as above]
  }
]
```

Comment: appreciated your effort. Let me have a look and get back soon.

Comment: Many thanks to you as it is working as expected now! Can I know why do we need have two category, one in outer and another one in products array? Btw I removed the async.

Comment: In this particular implementation, it would have been more trouble to try and remove the category from the individual products than it was worth for a Stack Overflow answer. You could certainly try to remove it, but it is probably not necessary.

Comment: Indeed, I will probably do it in the future when I have more understanding on this part. Thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: Hi Ben, for example I added a search bar. Can I implement the filter feature with this logic? The search bar can search for multiple fields e.g. code, desc, uom etc. Can you show me how?

Comment: Sure, Give it a shot, and reach out when you get stuck.